# Wowza records audio but without video

Tags: flash, recording, wowza

I have a Wowza Media Server 2 running on Amazon EC2 and I've noticed from time to time a flv is recorded from a webcam using Flash that has audio but no video. It works fine most of the time but from time to time this error occurs any ideas how I can prevent this. I know this is a vague i'm new to using wowza and not sure how to trace the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your video codec is H.264 and not VP6.